# Given three non-collinear points then those three points are distinct (Incidence geometry)

Tags: geometry

*If $A, B,$ and $C$ are non-collinear points, then $A$ and $B$ are distinct, and $C$ does not lie on the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$.*

---

The axioms are the following:

1. *Incidence Axiom 1*: There exist at least three distinct noncollinear
   points.
2. *Incidence Axiom 2*: Given any two distinct points, there is at least
   one line that contains both of them.
3. *Incidence Axiom 3*: Given any two distinct points, there is at most
   one line that contains both of them.
4. *Incidence Axiom 4*: Given any line, there are at least two distinct
   points that lie on it.

---

*Proof*:

I attempted to prove this by the contrapositive by assuming that $A$ and $B$ are equal points and arriving at a contradiction.

Suppose $A, B,$ and $C$ are non-collinear points and that $A=B$ then there is a line, $l$, that contains them. From Incidence Axiom 4, we know given any line $l$ there are at least two distinct points that lie on it, let this distinct point be $D$ therefore $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ (or similarly $\overleftrightarrow{BD}$ since $A=B$) is a line with two distinct points. Now since $C$ is collinear from $A$, we have that $C \notin \overleftrightarrow{AD}$ therefore $C$ is distinct from $A$ and $B$, however, since $A=B$ and $C$ are two distinct points we have from Incidence Axiom 3 that there is at most one line that contains both of them, however, this a contradiction since $C$ is collinear from $A$ therefore the assumption that $A=B$ is false.

---

Is my proof correct?

How can I expand on this theroem to prove that, $A$ does not lie on $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$, $B$ does not lie on $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and $C$ does not lie on $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$?

Comment: You'd better list the axioms you can use.

Comment: @Aretino Sorry i have added the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can conclude more quickly: if $A=B\ne C$ there is a line $l$ passing through $A$ and $C$ (Axiom 3), whence contradiction.

Once you know $A\ne B$, if $C\in \overleftrightarrow{AB}$ we get a contradiction, hence $C\not\in \overleftrightarrow{AB}$.